# regex to get last of repetition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below two strings. In both cases, I am trying to retrieve "foreclosure_defenses".

```
str = "client_profile[lead_profile_attributes][foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]"
str2 = "client_profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]"
```

I'm close but I can't get a regex that will work with both of them.

This regex works for str2, but not for str:

```
regex = /\w+(?:\[(\w+)_attributes\]+)\[\d+\]\[own_property\]/g 
regex.exec(str2)
["client_profile[foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]", "foreclosure_defenses"]
```

This regex works for str, but not for str2:

```
regex = /\w+(?:\[(\w+)_attributes\]?)+\[\d+\]\[own_property\]/g
regex.exec(str);
["client_profile[lead_profile_attributes][foreclosure_defenses_attributes][0][own_property]", "foreclosure_defenses"]
```

The last one should work for both cases, but doesn't. It should look for one or many _attributes patterns and grab the last one.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
/\w+(?:\[(\w+)_attributes\])+\[\d+\]\[own_property\]/
```

Note that if you use global `g` flag and you attempt to match multiple strings, you will need to reset the index of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this:

```
/.+?\[(foreclosure_defenses)_attributes\]/g
```

### [Demo](http://www.regexr.com/39tca)